# MySQL query hogging the CPU

Tags: mysql

I have had some issues with a site (basically MySQL is killing the proccessor)

I found the using `top` in the comand line showed me that it was MySQL throttling the proccessors.

So I ran the mysqladmin processlist command.

which showed

**ID**-----**user**-----**Host**-----**DB**-----**Command**-----**Time**-----**State**--------      **Info**

47-----XXX------XXX-------XXX----Query-----------2400-----Statistics----SELECT DISTINCT.....

I belive this is telling me that the above query is taking way too long, stuck or won't complete.

My developer has asked me if there is a way to determine any more information like what's generating this etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you've pasted shows that the query listed has been running for 2400 seconds, whether this is too long or longer than usual is impossible for anyone but you to say.

If you run a SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST instead of just SHOW PROCESSLIST, MySQL will tell you the full query being ran, not just the first few words.

Once you can see the exact query you're running, you / your developer should be able to find it in the source of the site using the database.

Comment: that gave me a better look at whats running thank you. and yes that would be too long nothing should take that long to process on the site / server etc. ty again

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use EXPLAIN on queries. It lists the tables in the output in the order that MySQL would read them while processing the statement.

Hope that might be of some help

Comment: how would one go about this i found mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G which was easy to impliment cant find anything about EXPLAIN sorry